# how to render a partial view on the masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Alright so here is the question.

I have a user class which contains a list of users named Friends.
I wish to show a list of friends in the right collumn on all my pages.

so i created a 3 collumn layout as a masterpage.
and in this friends column i RenderPartial("Friends");

Sadly this needs a model.
How can i access my DOCCL.Models.User class and loop through it's Friends in the friends list?

I don't understand how i can create a controller for this as my masterpage is not strongly typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call a child action from the master page.

Comment: How would i go about doing this?

Comment: `@Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName")` (or if you're using aspx view engine, `<% Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName") %>`)